# Unlimited trades

Tags: catan

Can a players trade with another player unlimited times in his same turn?

For example:
This is turn of player1 and he trades with player2 1:3 cards and than trade with player3 1:3 and than again trade with player2 in a loop. in this situation player 1 can start his turn with one card and finish his turn with 15+ cards.

Comment: You used the house rules tag, but you never elaborated why the default rules wouldn't suffice; needless to say, you can house-rule anything. What were you trying to do with that?

Comment: Could you give an actual situation where player2 and player3 would engage in this behaviour?

Answer (score 4):

**Yes, you may trade as many times as you want.**

In the exhaustive rules on trading from the Almanac section of the [current game rules](https://www.catan.com/sites/default/files/2021-06/catan_base_rules_2020_200707.pdf), you can find the following rule:

> You may trade as long as you have resource cards.

If that's not clear enough for some reason, the entire section doesn't mention any limits either, and if there were any restrictions on the amount of legal trades per turn, it would be mentioned there.